# Calling custom java class from python using JPype

Tags: java, python, classnotfoundexception, jpype

Getting class not found exception while trying to call java class from python using jpype. Below are version and path details:

JPype version:JPype1-py3

Python: 3.6

Java: 1.8.0_171

Java file path: /home/neha/Downloads/fontAttributes/PDFFontExtractor.java

Python file path: /home/neha/Downloads/call_java.py

Below is Python code: call_java.py

```
import jpype
from jpype import *
cpath="-Djava.class.path=%s" % ("/home/neha/Downloads")
startJVM(getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea",cpath)
Test = JClass('fontAttributes.PDFFontExtractor')
Test.getFontAttributes()
java.lang.System.out.println(str)
shutdownJVM()
```

Output:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "call_java.py", line 14, in <module>
Test = JClass('fontAttributes.PDFFontExtractor')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jpype/_jclass.py", line 55, in JClass
raise _RUNTIMEEXCEPTION.PYEXC("Class %s not found" % name)
jpype._jexception.ExceptionPyRaisable: java.lang.Exception: Class fontAttributes.PDFFontExtractor not found
```

Comment: Have you compiled the Java class?  In other words, does a file `PDFFontExtractor.class` exist in the same folder as `PDFFontExtractor.java`?

Comment: Yes but now the code is working.

Comment: I didn't add jar files in the cpath.